# How to highlight all symbol appearances in python code with PTVS?

Tags: python, visual-studio-2013, ptvs

I am using [PTVS 2.2 for VS2013](https://github.com/Microsoft/PTVS/releases/v2.2) for my Python project. I found 2 important features seem missing for code editing:

- **Reference Highlighting**: When I highlight a symbol by double clicking it, I want all the appearances of this symbol to be highlighted as well. It could help me identify the symbol's usage quickly.
- **Refactoring**: When I change a symbol, all its appearances should be changed accordingly.

  But PTVS is not doing that (see below). Or do I misconfigured it?

[image]

Comment: Highlighting is a missing feature:
https://github.com/Microsoft/PTVS/issues/76

Comment: @PavelMinaev Thanks for the info. Hope you can add it in v.next.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reference highlighting, I found below extension. **But it's dumb because it's not case-sensitive**.

[Highlight all occurrences of selected word](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/2a3c622e-f99b-4da1-b430-e1bf37fe93e7)

For Refactoring, it turns out i need to right click and select refactor first. It's a bit tedious, but at least works.

[image]

Ref:

[Highlight references when cursor is on an identifier #76](https://github.com/Microsoft/PTVS/issues/76)

[PTVS refactoring](https://github.com/Microsoft/PTVS/wiki/Refactoring)